# Day 1 return rate across all users for each date

Tags: sql

I got this question during an interview and I wanted to verify the approach.

Write a SQL statement that calculates the day 1 return rate across all users for each date. The "Day 1 return rate" is the %
of distinct users seen on day n, that are also seen on day (n+1). We want to track user return rate day over day.

e.g. For the sample data above:
-

1. D1RR for 2021-09-01 is 50%.
2. D1RR for 2021-09-02 is 0%

*/

My idea is get count of distinct users who logged on day 1. user_id,min(date), then keep calculating over other dates.

```
CREATE TABLE bi_staging.sessions (
  session_ts TIMESTAMP,
    user_id string,
    app_name string
)

 INSERT INTO bi_staging.sessions(session_ts, user_id, app_name)
 VALUES
 ('2021-09-01 06:00:00', '123', 'ios'),
 ('2021-09-01 12:30:00', '123', 'ios'),
 ('2021-09-02 06:00:00', '123', 'ios'),
 ('2021-09-01 06:00:00', 'abc', 'ios'),
 ('2021-09-03 06:00:00', 'abc', 'ios');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple solution can be something like the following one:

NOTE: I've used `datetime` instead of `timestamp` to simplify my tests. In this solution will be needed a method to convert a `timestamp` to a `date`

```
DECLARE @temp TABLE (session_ts_date DATE, user_id Varchar(10))
    
INSERT INTO @temp(session_ts_date, user_id)
    SELECT DISTINCT CAST(session_ts AS DATE),
                    user_id
    FROM @sessions
    
SELECT s.session_ts_date,
       CAST(SUM( CASE WHEN t.user_id IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) as DECIMAL)/ CAST(count(s.user_id) AS DECIMAL)
FROM @temp s
    LEFT JOIN @temp t on s.session_ts_date = DATEADD(day,-1,t.session_ts_date) and s.user_id = t.user_id
GROUP BY s.session_ts_date
```

Comment: Easy to understand and simple. Got stuck answering this since I tried with lead/lag functions.